# Why can't I login?

Tags: league-of-legends

[image: The Error]

I had this issue for over a month now, Searched the whole internet, tried using public dns settings, uninstalled my antivirus, disabled my firewall, tried opening the client as administrator, reinstalled once, tried using an ethernet cable instead of wifi.

Comment: Did you do something to get banned possibly? [It's possible that that's why](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=283616).  (Maybe)

Comment: Do you know anyone else that can try to login on your computer and see what happens? A friend perhaps?

Comment: Nope, I didnt do anything in particular, and my friends already tried and gave up xD

Comment: And nope... unlike that guy i tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a password change, or a ban. Have you checked your email for any notice from Riot Games? A possible but unlikely third option is that you have blocked the port to LoL on your router. I suggest checking that as well.

So you can do 2 things

1. Contact Riot games about your account

   - Recovering your account can be done [here](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201751694)
   - in case your account got suspended you can get help [here](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201898070)
2. Check if you enabled your [ports](https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/network-protection-firewall-nat-qos-ips/41362/port-forwarding-league-of-legends)

> 5000 - 5500 UDP - League of Legends Game Client
>       8393 - 8400 TCP - Patcher and Maestro
>       2099 TCP - PVP.Net
>       5223 TCP - PVP.Net
>       5222 TCP - PVP.Net
>       80 TCP - HTTP Connections
>       443 TCP - HTTPS Connections
>       8088 Spectator Mode

Comment: Lemme try that :o

Comment: Tried that and added all the above... Didnt work.. Anyways im gonna reinstall the game and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I guess the only thing you can do is wait for a reply from Riot Games help desk

Comment: I tried again with a fresh installation, still the same error, wtf?

Comment: Try contacting the Riot support, all you can do. Or use another account and try that. A last thing you can do is look at the country you live and that internet provider and see if they have blocked LoL there.

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot you have shared is recent, the problem might be that you have an outdated client. The current version of LoL is 7.8, but your screenshot shows 7.7. You might need to update.

Another problem might be that you are using the legacy client. Since about a week ago, the [legacy client has been retired](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/legacy-client-now-retired) and you will need to use the new client to log in.

Comment: That's not true for every server. EUW and EUNE for example will only have it retired on the 3rd of next month

Comment: The screenshot i shared was taken when it was 7.7, I thought patching would solve the issue so i waited for another patch but nope.